# HTML5 Canvas API on a memory-saving 1bit per pixel CanvasRenderingContext?

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a way to use the HTML5 Canvas API on a memory-saving 1bit per pixel CanvasRenderingContext?

I'd like to create reverse lookup buffers for graphical objects that should receive interaction. There should be a buffer (w*h*1 bit) for each interactive object. Those pixels where the object is touchable would have the value 1 (it's like creating a mask per object).

Then the question which objects are active in a visualization can simply be answered by asking each reverse lookup buffer if it's colored 'black' at mouse position x/y.

I'd like to use this approach to ease the process of adding interaction to canvas-based visualizations.

In practice you would simply have to implement a draw(ctx) method (as usual) and only if you want to have interaction, an additional mask(reverselookupbuffer) method that marks the area where the object should be touchable (e.g. simply a rectangle in case of some text)

To implement this efficiently I need a simple pixel buffer that only stores 1bit per pixel. I don't need colors here.

With an additional, ordinaray canvas element I'd need lots of memory for storing masks for e.g. 100 touchable objects)

on a 800x600 canvas that would result in 800*600*32*100 bit = 183 MB, but only 5.6MB if I'd use a 1-bit bitmap.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks a lot,

Michael

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just store the x,y,width,height for each of your interactive elements and then just check for mouse down within one of those? Much lighter on memory and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes that's how I used to do it. However that approach is rather expensive as you always have to implement those checkSelected() range checks using lots of math. (like http://github.com/michael/donut/blob/master/donut.pjs#L150) with. Moreover you always have to iterate over all objects to find those, which are in the range. (http://github.com/michael/donut/blob/master/donut.pjs#L488)

Suppose you have a star shape. That's pretty hard to implement. Isn't it? ;)

Comment: I'm working on a simple SceneGraph library (inspired by Protovis) on top of canvas as a part of my visualization toolkit (http://github.com/michael/unveil). I'd like to provide a simple approach to add interaction to SceneGraph Nodes (=graphical objects).

When using SVG you can simply bind event handlers to SVG Elements. In comparison it's rather hard do that with Canvas. That's why I want to take action. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Cake.js implements what you're looking for http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/. It's no longer being maintained though, so you could pick it up.

Comment: Hm.. I can't locate those pieces of code. Just found out he's using isPointInPath(), which I wasn't aware of. Maybe that's worth consideration. I mean the touchable areas could be checked by using isPointInPath(). Looking into it.

Comment: Ahh there is it: handlePick() does the check, and drawPickingPath() needs to be implemented for interactive elements. I'm still not sure if it supports event bubbling. Needs more investigation ;-) Thanks for pointing me there!

Comment: Got it working basically:

http://quasipartikel.at/unveil/examples/random_bars.html

Use Google chrome please, it's not working in Firefox for some reason....

http://quasipartikel.at/unveil/examples/random_bars.html

Code: http://gist.github.com/477787

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my reply's a bit late and simple - with WebGL what people are doing is a pick-mode rendering pass on mouse down -

1. mouse down at (x,y)
2. set 1x1 pixel viewport {x,y, x+1,y+1)
3. render display list, with a separate arbitrary color for each element, mapped to the element
4. then (after Z-buffering) the 1x1 pixel frame buffer contains a single pixel of the colour of the nearest element - read the pixel and find the mapped element

Well that's theory!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's good to know anyway. :)

However for me ctx.isPointInPath() does a perfect job so far. Seems like I'll stick with that.